# How to limit/control sampling rate in Apache Jmeter?

Tags: apache, jmeter

Ok, so I have control over the below parameters in Apache JMeter:

1. Number of Threads (users)
2. Ramp-up period (in seconds)

How do I test for varying sampling rate and not varying user addition rate? Even a fixed sampling rate would do.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Got my answer :)

Sampling rate can be limited by setting timer parameter.

Right click on your test plan, then Add, then Timers.
There are a varieties of timers to cater to various needs. I used constant timer in my case.

Answer (score 3):

Particular timer you need is: http://code.google.com/p/jmeter-plugins/wiki/ThroughputShapingTimer

Answer (score 3):

Constant Throughput Timer is excellent to regulate the number of hits without changing the threads and/or delays.

http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Constant_Throughput_Timer

It can also be controlled from outside (not easy).